# how to get current htmlSelectElements id

Tags: javascript, html

hi i have been trying to get the id of the current element that I am looping through but I am not sure why this doesnt work any help is greatly appreciated!

code:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var key = "";
    var value = "";
    if (arr[i].nodeName == "INPUT" || arr[i].nodeName == "TEXTAREA") {
        key = arr[i].name;
        value = arr[i].value;
    }
    else if (arr[i].nodeName == "SELECT" && arr[i].attr('id') == "multiple") {
        alert("worked");
        key = arr[i].name;
        value = "multi";
    }
    else if (arr[i].nodeName == "SELECT" && arr[i].attr('id') != "multiple") {
        alert("ddint work");
        key = arr[i].name;
        value = "not multi";
    }
}​
```

I am not able to get the id from my arr[i] position even though it is an element.

Comment: Which not just check the `id` attribute?

Comment: what do you mean i am checking the id attribute?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` doesn't return an array of jQuery objects. Also, it doesn't even exist in older versions of IE just as a heads up.

Comment: @arrowill12: `arr[i].id` will give you the ID - that's all you need.

Comment: DOMt nodes don't have a `attr` method.

Comment: not sure why i didnt think of this! thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr[i]` is an element, not a jQuery object. you can access the `id` property directly with `arr[i].id`

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var key = "";
    var value = "";
    if (arr[i].nodeName == "INPUT" || arr[i].nodeName == "TEXTAREA") {
        value = arr[i].value;
    }
    else if (arr[i].nodeName == "SELECT" && arr[i].id == "multiple") {
        alert("worked");
        value = "multi";
    }
    else if (arr[i].nodeName == "SELECT" && arr[i].id != "multiple") {
        alert("ddint work");
        value = "not multi";
    }
    key = arr[i].name;
}​
```

.attr("id") is a jquery function. The javascript equivalent is .id

Also you can move the key variable assignment outside of the if statements because you assign it regardless of the if statements.

Answer (score -1):

using .id on a node is not recommended. use .getAttribute.